# Object Refrence in javascript does not work Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append the parent node with child node using jquery and object oriented 
javascript.

Can you please explain why the commented line in the buildexpenseTable function block does not work.

But the next line works fine.

```
var BUILD = BUILD || {};

BUILD.protoType = {
    expenseDiv : function(bearer){
        return "<P>hai</p>";
    }
}

BUILD.builder = {
    bearer : $("#bearer"),
    desc : $("#description"),
    amount : $("#amount"),
    output : $("#outputBlock"),
    buildExpenseTable : function (){
        //BUILD.builder.output.append($(BUILD.protoType.expenseDiv(bearer.value)));
        $("#outputBlock").append($(BUILD.protoType.expenseDiv(bearer.value)));
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? which line does not work? also `bearer.value` may be falsy since bearer is a jQuery object and hence .value might not work here

Comment: The commented line in the code sample does not append the child node. bearer.value does not cause any issues It returns the value without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a function. `output` is populated (and thus `$('outputBlock')` is executed) when `BUILD.builder` is *created*. If you use the second statement, `$('outputBlock')` is executed when  `buildExpenseTable` is *called*.

Most probably, `BUILD.builder` is initialized before the page has been entirely loaded and the DOM has been built, so `BUILD.builder.output` will be empty.

Note that, further, the way you do it will cause `$('#bearer')`, `$('#description')`, etc. to be executed only *once*, namely at the time `BUILD.builder` is created; thus any subsequent changes to the DOM are ignored. That's probably not what you want?

You can solve the problem by doing this:

```
BUILD.builder = {
    bearer : function () { return $("#bearer") },
    desc : function () { return $("#description") },
    amount : function () { return $("#amount") },
    output : function () { return $("#outputBlock") },
    buildExpenseTable : function (){
        BUILD.builder.output ().append($(BUILD.protoType.expenseDiv(BUILD.builder.bearer ().value)));
    }
}
```

If you are absolutely sure that you really want a "once-and-forever" initialization, put the initialization of `BUILD.builder` into a `$(document).ready (...)` handler, yet I would rather not do that.

Second mistake: You probably won't find `bearer`, as you did not indicate the object where to look for it.

Comment: i have called the output in this line BUILD.builder.output.append($(BUILD.protoType.expenseDiv(bearer.value))); . but why it doesnt work.

Comment: No, you haven't called `output`, as `output` is not a function. You've populated `output` with the result of `$('#outputBlock')` once, and then you're simply reading the stored value. If `$('#outputBlock')` does not find the element at the time `BUILD.builder` is created, you won't ever find it with your method, as you do not execute `$('#outputBlock')` a second time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation john. I am intializing it only one time using this statement.var BUILD = BUILD || {}; If i intialize Build every time, will my line of code BUILD.builder.output.append($(BUILD.protoType.expenseDiv(bearer.value))); executes with out any issues. Am I getting it correct?

Comment: I understand why my line wont work.but the second mistake does not valid isnt it? john. bearer.value will return the stored values without any issues. Because i could not find any issue in the browser.

Comment: Well, then you have another variable `bearer` somewhere, I guess? I am pretty sure that your `bearer` is not identical to `BUILD.builder.bearer`.